# не работает pjax form

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

Здравствуйте, проблема такая сайт без фрэмворков на чистом php и на хостинге не vps , на сайте есть pjax по ссылкам переходит без перезагрузки страниц, а вот форму обработать не может страница перезагружается в чем проблема понять не могу

```js
$(function () {
    $(document).pjax('a', '#pjax-container', {
        fragment: '#pjax-container',
        maxCacheLength: 20000000000,
        timeout: 65000000000,
        container: '#pjax-container'
    });

$(document).on('submit', 'form[data-pjax]', function(event) {
  $.pjax.submit(event, '#j-f-form')
})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax/master/jquery.pjax.js"></script>
<form data-pjax name="form" id="j-f-form" class="mt-5" action="flt.php" method="post">
   <select class="w-100"  name="speed" id="speed">
      <option value="">Выберите район</option>
      <option value="6">Кировский</option>
      <option value="5">Лениский</option>
      <option value="4">Дзержинский</option>
      <option value="7">Заволжский</option>
      <option value="8">Красноперекопский</option>
      <option value="9">Фрунзенский</option>
   </select>
   <p class="w-100 mt-3">Количество комнат</p>
   <label for="checkbox-1"><span class="text-check">1</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-1" value="1">
   <label for="checkbox-2"><span class="text-check">2</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-2" value="2">
   <label for="checkbox-3"><span class="text-check">3</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-3" value="3">
   <label for="checkbox-4"><span class="text-check">4+</span></label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-4" value="4">
   <p class="mt-2">Цена:</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text"  name="price_start" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="От">
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <input type="text" name="price_end" class="form-control" id="price2" placeholder="До">
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" name="filter" value="Подобрать квартиры" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Главной проблемой было не понимание, что я работаю не с yii2 фреймворком, а просто с php на хостинге и тут важно, что я работаю с опцией fragment: '#pjax-container', . А так же очень важный параметр является type: "POST"
без него данные не будут отпправлятся

```js
   $(document).on("submit", "form", function(event) {
        $.pjax.submit(event, "#pjax-container", {
        fragment: '#pjax-container', 
        maxCacheLength: 2000, 
        timeout: 6500, 
        type: "POST"})
    });
```

```html
          <form class="mt-5" action="flt.php" method="POST">
     <select class="w-100"  name="speed" id="speed">
      <option value="">Выберите район</option>
      <option value="6">Кировский</option>
      <option value="5">Лениский</option>
      <option value="4">Дзержинский</option>
      <option value="7">Заволжский</option>
      <option value="8">Красноперекопский</option>
      <option value="9">Фрунзенский</option>
    </select>

    <p class="w-100 mt-3">Количество комнат</p>
    <label for="checkbox-1"><span class="text-check">1</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-1" value="1">
    <label for="checkbox-2"><span class="text-check">2</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-2" value="2">
    <label for="checkbox-3"><span class="text-check">3</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-3" value="3">
    <label for="checkbox-4"><span class="text-check">4+</span></label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="appartament[]" class="input" id="checkbox-4" value="4">
 
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="filter">

    <p class="mt-2">Цена:</p>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text"  name="price_start" class="form-control" id="price" placeholder="От">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="text" name="price_end" class="form-control" id="price2" placeholder="До">
    </div>
  </div>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4" id="j-f-form" name="filter" value="Подобрать квартиры" />
          </form>
```